# SEMGREX rule in stanford corenlp to have multiple words match with the same label

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, part-of-speech

I need help with SEMGREX rules. I have this sentence fragment:

```
including a draw down magnet that generates a distinct electromagnetic field.
```

which has dependencies like this:

[image]

With this rule:

```
((({pos:/NN.*/}=target ?>compound {pos:/NN.*/}=compl  )?>amod {pos:/JJ.*|VB.*/}=adj  ) ?>/nmod.*/ {pos:/NN.*/}=adjn  )  >det {word:/a|an/}=art
```

I get this matching:
[image]

How would I change the rule to get both 'distinct' and 'electromagnetic' as AMODs of the NN field with the 'adj' label?